# How can I run a notebook from another notebook multiple times?

Tags: notebooks

I have a notebook which I want to execute multiple times and changing one parameter each time. Intuitively, I want to do something like this:

```
Table[
        FolderNumber= i; (*  this is the variable inside NoteBookToRun *)
        nb = NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], NoteBookToRun}]];
        SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
        SelectionEvaluate[nb];

            {ResultsFromNoteBookToRun},
        {i, 1, NumberOfFolders}
     ]
```

Obviously this won't work because the Table needs to finish before the targeted notebook will execute, so the maximum number I think this can work for is 2.

How can I get my notebook to run multiple times while changing a parameter inside the notebook I want to run?

Comment: Take your notebook code and turn it into a bunch of functions. Save those as a package, maybe. This is what packages are built for. Then you can load the package and call some function that just runs the script.

Comment: That's certainly an option but at this point I would prefer to have a solution where I can just call the notebook -- if possible. If it isn't then I will close the question and just do it manually

Comment: ...why would you willingly make your life harder like that? Turning the script into a bunch of functions will be almost zero work

Comment: As I said, that is an alternative to what I am asking. If what I am asking is not possible within M, then your suggestion is the answer. But for now what you suggest is NOT an answer to my question...I may as well just stick a loop around my script...there are reasons I don't want to break my code down.

Comment: [Question 67050](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67050/1063) and the answers to it may provide some insights.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thanks for this. Although I'm not quite sure how this helps? As I understand it this can just tell me if the notebook has been executed, is that correct?

Comment: You can define a `context` that is shared between the two notebooks in order to share variables between them.  After the called notebook returns, store the answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey would you be willing to construct a rough example in answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with your intended code...

```
Table[
        FolderNumber= i; (*  this is the variable inside NoteBookToRun *)
        nb = NotebookOpen[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], NoteBookToRun}]];
        SelectionMove[nb,All,Notebook];
        SelectionEvaluate[nb];

            {ResultsFromNoteBookToRun},
        {i, 1, NumberOfFolders}
     ]
```

...as you know, `SelectionEvaluate` is a poor choice for this because all it does it to *queue* the evaluation, not perform the evaluation and wait for a response.  What you probably don't realize is that the similarly-named `NotebookEvaluate` function (available since v8) is much more powerful and does something very different.  It evaluates the notebook synchronously, not returning until the notebook is fully evaluated -- not unlike evaluating a package.

`NotebookEvaluate` can insert the results or not depending upon the `InsertResults` option.  And you don't even have to visibly open and close notebook windows.  `NotebookEvaluate`, if given a filename for a notebook which is currently unopened, will invisibly open, evaluate, and close the window (saving if needed to insert results).

Changing your proposed code to use `NotebookEvaluate` is pretty straightforward:

```
Table[
        FolderNumber= i; (*  this is the variable inside NoteBookToRun *)
        NotebookEvaluate[FileNameJoin[{Directory[], NoteBookToRun}]];
            {ResultsFromNoteBookToRun},
        {i, 1, NumberOfFolders}
     ]
```

This version follows the default behavior to not insert the results into the notebooks, but if you wish to change that, simply add `InsertResults->True`.

Comment: Enjoy that delicious bounty!! Brilliant this is exactly what I was after. I am sure there are more elegant methods using modules but this fits my needs right now perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

I have not used this code in quite a while but I think it still works.  The calling notebook could be

```
Dynamic[{loop, linked`vdtdz}]
distab = {}; Dynamic[distab // TableForm]
Dynamic[return]

Do[linked`vdtdz = 0.1 loop; linked`$callingNotebook = EvaluationNotebook[];
return = NotebookEvaluate[$UserDocumentsDirectory<>"/Mathematica/PSTD_Solve.nb"];
distab = Append[distab, linked`maxai], {loop, 8, 10}]
```

It passes a variable

```
linked`vdtdz
```

and saves the returned variable

```
linked`maxai
```

It also temporarily displays a pair of plots produced by the called notebook.

The called notebook begins with

```
linked = ValueQ[linked`$callingNotebook]; Clear[linked`$callingNotebook]
```

which determines whether the called notebook actually has been called by another notebook, as opposed to being run on its own.  Later, the called notebook uses the passed variable

```
vdtdz = If[linked, linked`vdtdz, 1.0]; \[CapitalDelta]t0 = vdtdz \[CapitalDelta]z0/vz0
```

Still later, the called notebook saves plots to disk, depending on whether it actually has been called by another notebook.

```
If[linked, saveplot = True, (*other code*)]
```

On its **last** line of code, the called notebook stores the answer to be returned to the calling notebook and also creates a final pair of plots which automatically are returned.

```
If[linked, linked`maxai = kout[[1, 4]]; Grid[{{grow3D, growContour}}]]
```

This may be more than you want.  If so, delete what is unnecessary (the plots and the use of `Dynamic`, for instance).